# Evaluate $\int \frac{1}{x^3+3x+1}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Evaluate $$\int \frac{1}{x^3+3x+1}dx$$
I tried to evaluate it but I couldn't  do .

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I couldnt start.

Comment: @Power: Are you sure that it is $x^3$ in the denumerator?

Comment: @DennisGulko, yes I am sure

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The polynomial $x^3+3x+1$ has exactly $1$ real root (at $a\sim-0.32$, according to [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E3%2B3x%2B1)), and hence two complex-conjugate roots. So $x^3+3x+1=(x-a)(x^2+bx+c)$ where $b^2-4c<0$. So your steps would be the following:
1) Break $\frac1{x^3+3x+1}$ as 
$$\frac1{x^3+3x+1}=\left(\frac1{x-a}-\frac{x+(a+b)}{x^2+bx+c}\right)\frac1{a^2+ab+c}$$
(open parenthesis to check)
2) Integrate, remembering that 
$$\frac{1}{x^2+bx+c}=\frac{1}{\left(x+\frac b2\right)^2+c-\frac{b^2}4}$$
and that $b^2-4c<0$, hence $4c-b^2>0$.

Comment: nice, was just about to post this idea for a solution.

Comment: The real root is $2\sinh\left(\frac13\sinh^{-1}\left(-\frac12\right)\right)=-0.322185354626085$. This is because $(2\sinh(u))^3+3(2\sinh(u))=2\sinh(3u)$. Let $x=2\sinh(u)$.

Comment: @robjohn Could you please elaborate how you calculated the root?

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi: as the comment says, let $x=2\sinh(u)$, then if we know that $2\sinh(3u)=-1$, we know that $x^3+3x=-1$. Thus, $x=2\sinh(u)=2\sinh\left(\frac13\sinh^{-1}\left(-\frac12\right)\right)$

Answer (score 4):

By setting $x=2z$ we have
$$I=\int\frac{dx}{x^3+3x+1}=\int\frac{dz}{4z^3+3z+1/2}$$
and by replacing $z$ with $\sinh t$, then $t$ with $\log u$,  we have:
$$ I = \int \frac{\cosh t}{1/2+\sinh(3t)}\,dt =\int\frac{u^3+u}{u^6+u^3-1}\,du$$
that is a bit better to deal with and, more important, gives that:
$$ 4z^3+3z+1/2 = \left(z+\sinh\frac{\operatorname{arcsinh} 1/2}{3}\right)\left(4z^2-4\sinh\frac{\operatorname{arcsinh} 1/2}{3}z+\frac{1}{2\sinh\frac{\operatorname{arcsinh} 1/2}{3}}\right)$$
so we have the roots of $x^3+3x+1$ in a explicit trigonometric form and we can compute $I$ through partial fraction decomposition. We also have:
$$\operatorname{arcsinh}\frac{1}{2}=\log\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right).$$

Comment: I think you need to have $\mathrm{arcsinh(1/2)}$. I computed the root in a comment to Dennis Gulko's answer.

Comment: @robjohn: we are dealing with different polynomials, I checked my last line and it looks to hold.

Comment: Then setting $x=2z$ wouldn't the integral be $\int\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{4z^3+3z+\frac12}$?

Comment: @robjohn: Whoops, you're right, now fixed.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio As always, a very creative approach!!  I always enjoy reading your answers!  Just curious ... Why do you believe that expressing the roots in trigonometric form is superior to expressing the roots in terms of nested cube and square roots (i.e., the brute force characterization)?  What does one gain from either a numerical application or a theoretical one?  For example, if you have a look at my "answer" herein, how would the form of the roots enhance the answer of facilitate numerical approximation?

Comment: @Dr.MV: it is just a matter of "beauty" to have the roots as values of inverse trigonometric functions. I just wanted to write them down in a explicit form.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio  Mission accomplished.

Answer (score 1):

Using partial fraction expansion gives,

$$\int \frac{1}{x^3+3x+1}dx=\int \left(\frac{a_1}{x-x_1}+\frac{a_2}{x-x_2}+\frac{a_3}{x-x_3}\right)dx$$

where $x_1$, $x_2$, and $x_3$ are the roots (which can be found in closed form) and the constants $a_i$, $i=1,2,3$ are given by $a_i=\frac{1}{3x_i^2+3}$.

Note that here, only one root is real (say $x_1$ is real).  Then, $x_2$ and $x_3$ are complex conjugates and $a_1$ and $a_2$ are complex conjugates.  Thus, the integral simplifies to 
$$\int \frac{1}{x^3+3x+1}dx=a_1\log |x-x_1|+2\Re \left(a_2\log (x-x_2)\right)+C$$

where $\Re \left(a_2\log (x-x_2)\right)$ is the real part of $a_2\log (x-x_2)$ and $C$ is a constant of integration.  Writing

$$a_{2r}=\Re (a_2)$$
$$a_{2i}=\Im (a_2)$$
$$x_{2r}=\Re (x_2)$$
$$x_{2i}=\Im (2_2)$$

the integral becomes
$$\int \frac{1}{x^3+3x+1}dx=a_1\log |x-x_1|+a_{2r}\log \left((x-x_{2r})^2+x_{2i}^2\right)+2a_{2i}\arctan \left(\frac{x_{2i}}{x-x_{2r}}\right)+C$$

Comment: Only one of them is real...

Comment: Yes, that is true. Partial fraction expansion is valid for complex roots.

Comment: Indeed it is - but you need to know complex integration for that

Comment: That is not true.  Each partial fraction integrates to $\log(x-x_i)$.

Comment: Which is what exactly? When you learn\teach Calculus 1, do you talk about $\log(x-2i+3)$?

Comment: Actually, $\frac{1}{z}$ is not $\log$'s derivative everywhere... 
Remember that $Ln(z)$ is not entire.

Comment: I'm not quite sure of your point.  The OP didn't state anything about restrictions on use of complex arithmetic.

Comment: @Jolly One needs to cut the plane; that's all.